# How to use assumptions without Simplify[]?

Tags: assumptions

[image: Example program]

According to this simple example program, the assumptions evaluated only with the Simplify[] function call. However, I wouldn't like to use Simplify[] because it can be very slow with longer expressions.

I would like the Conjugate[c10] function call to give me the c10 output after the assumption is defined. Is there a way to do this?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

$Assumptions := True
Conjugate[c10]
Refine[Conjugate[c10]]
Simplify[Conjugate[c10]]
$Assumptions

$Assumptions := c10 \[Element] Reals
Conjugate[c10]
Refine[Conjugate[c10]]
Simplify[Conjugate[c10]]
$Assumptions

ClearAll["Global`*"]
$Assumptions
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect) [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate) to get the behavior you want, although it will undoubtedly slow down computations involving [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate):

```
SetConjugateSimplification[bool_] := (
    Unprotect[Conjugate];
    If[TrueQ @ bool,
        Conjugate[e_] /; !TrueQ@$Flag := Block[{$Flag=True}, Simplify @ Conjugate[e]],

        DownValues[Conjugate] = {}
    ];
    Protect[Conjugate];
)
```

Then, turn on conjugate simplification:

```
SetConjugateSimplification[True]
```

Now, [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate) will use assumptions specified with [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions) or [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming):

```
$Assumptions = c10 ∈ Reals;
Conjugate[c10]
```

> c10

Restore the usual [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate) behavior:

```
SetConjugateSimplification[False]
```

Another possibility is to use [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues):

```
c10 /: Conjugate[c10]:= c10
```

Then:

```
Conjugate[c10]
Conjugate[c10+x]
Conjugate[Exp[c10 x]]
```

> c10
>
> c10 + Conjugate[x]
>
> E^(c10 Conjugate[x])